# Applying an option to all opened files in Vim

Tags: vim, vimdiff

I do a vimdiff on 2 files. Now if I want to wrap 2 files then I need to apply `:set wrap` 2 times to each file separately.

Is there any way I can apply `set wrap` to both of them simultaneously without running same command twice?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

windo does exactly what you want:

```
:windo set wrap
```

If you have multiple tabs, there is an equivalent `tabdo` to handle that case.

```
:tabdo set wrap
```

Comment: Similarly `:bufdo` exists if you want to apply an option to all current buffers.

Comment: Not *exactly*: this changes wrap mode for all windows, not only for those windows displaying a diff.  Use `:windo if &diff | setl wrap | endif` to set the option only for the diff windows.

Comment: @Xavier T. Not applicable here: `wrap` is window-local so you may observe unexpected behavior (`:h local-options`). It will also switch current buffer what is highly annoying especially in `vimdiff` mode.

Comment: any chance you know a similar approach to multiple open terminals in tmux ?  I use tmux with multiple vim instances and I find my self using set nowrap many times across these instances - it would be nice to make some sort of global command that could do this

Answer (score 1):

Found this solution using bash alias. I could not find a way to use `.vimrc` to set wrap for vimdiff.

```
alias vimdiff='vimdiff -c"windo set wrap" $*'
```

Credit to: http://www.nieko.net/data/bashrc